# In Animation Nodes how can I have an integer value increase from 0 to 100 and back to 0? (0 -> 100 -> 0)

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to create a smooth animation loop with a **Euler Wiggle** node and I have been unable to figure it out.

My goal is to provide an increasing integer value to the **Evolution** property and then when it hits a max, say 100, it would decrease to 0. This would allow me to create a longer animation with the Video Sequence Editor and save me having to render an excessive amount of frames.

I cannot use a simple duplicate sequence in reverse to emulate the effect as there is a background element that maintains the same direction of movement.

[image: Euler Wiggle Node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, the mathematical way, and the simple method of using an linear mirror interpolation which I will describe here:

[image: Node Tree 1]

In that case, it will start at zero, start increasing till it reach 100 at half the duration, and then start decreasing till it reach zero again at the full duration.

Comment: For future readers: Mirror Interpolation was missing from my menu and I found it using the search function.